# Generics not finding the type when calling onSuccess

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have a class that has a generic type of `TYPE: Animal`.

```
sealed class Animal {
}   

class Command<TYPE: Animal> (
    val onSuccess: (animal: TYPE) -> Unit
)
```

Later when I try to use the command I get a compile time error that `onSuccess` expects `Nothing`.

```
fun test(command: Command<*>) {
    val dog = dogMaker()
    command.onSuccess(dog) // PROBLEM
}
```

If I don't use generic, then `onSuccess` works, but I need generics because the command could be for any kind of animal.

1. Why is this error happening?
2. How to fix it?

Comment: If `test()` wants to pass a `Dog` to the `command` that was passed to it, then `Command` *has* to be a `Command<Dog>`. If you passed a `Command<Cat>`, it would crash when you tried to call `onSuccess` on it with a `Dog`. When you use `<*>` as the type, it means you don't know anything about the type so the only valid thing you could pass is `Nothing`, which is a subtype of everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add generic type for `test` function parameter:

```
fun test(command: Command<Animal>) {
    val dog = dogMaker()
    command.onSuccess(dog)
}
```

EDIT:

BTW you can remove generic type of `Command` class:

```
class Command (val onSuccess: (animal: Animal) -> Unit)

fun test(command: Command) {
    val dog = dogMaker()
    command.onSuccess(dog)
}
```

Comment: Ok but that requires casting when I call test. So let's say `test(command: Command<*>)` how would the casting look like inside the function?

Comment: You can't use `*` in generic type here. `Command` is a parameterized type, generic type should be specified.

Answer (score 0):

> **1. Why is this error happening**

You're using the [star-projection syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#star-projections) which in this case, since `TYPE` is an invariant type parameter with an upper bound `Animal`, means that

- for reading values, `command` is considered to be of type `Command<out Animal>` and
- for writing values, `command` is considered to be of type `Command<in Nothing>`.

> **2. How to fix it?**

It depends what you want to do.  It appears that you want to allow the caller to pass in any `Command` (it's type parameter being any `Animal` subtype).  It also appears that you always want to be able to call the `onSuccess` method with a `Dog`, regardless of the type argument of `Command`.  In that case the `onSuccess` method could accept `Animal` instead of `TYPE`:

```
val onSuccess: (animal: Animal) -> Unit
```

But if that's the only method then the `TYPE` type parameter is not even necessary.  So maybe you want to do something else, but then you have to specify what you want to achieve.